# NSNSInternalInconsistencyException, Missing outlet IOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Okay, I am stumped... all the answers related missing outlets point to making sure that the outlet is connected.  I have made sure that it is.  You can see it in the screenshots below.  The problem is that the code runs in IOS5.0.  So this is definitely some compatibility related issue.  I have also tried what was suggested in the two answers.  But that doesn't help.

Here is the code that invokes the xib.  Any clues?  Thank you for helping.

```
- (id) initWithModuleDataDict:(id)dataObject andStepNumber:(int)stepNumber
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"PhoneContent" bundle:nil])) {
        self.moduleData = (NSDictionary *)dataObject;
        self.module = [self.moduleData objectForKey:kModuleClassKey];
        numberOfSteps = [[self.module steps] count];
        self.doShowMeasurementViews = self.module.doShowMeasurementViews;

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

        // view controllers are created lazily in the loadScrollViewWithPage: method...
        // in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
        NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfSteps; i++)
        {
            [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
        self.viewControllers = controllers;

        //        CGRect fullScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        CGRect fullScreenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 372);
        UIScrollView *theScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
        self.scrollView = theScrollView;
        [theScrollView release];
        CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 20);
        UIPageControl *thePageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:bottomRect];
        thePageControl.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 400.0);
        self.pageControl = thePageControl;
        [thePageControl release];


        // a page is the width of the scroll view
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * numberOfSteps, scrollView.frame.size.height);
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast; //shp

        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfSteps;
        pageControl.currentPage = stepNumber;

        // Create the transition sound
        // Create the url for the source audio file (URLForResource:withExtension: method is new in 4.0)
        NSURL *purrSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"purr" 
                                                  withExtension:@"aiff"];
        // Store the url as a CFURLRef instance
        self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef)[purrSound retain];    
        // Create a system sound object representing the sound file
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

        [controllers release];

    }
    return self;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had mixed experiences porting and upgrading old xibs to the new Xcode.
What I have done in these instances is just make a new xib file and copy and paste the controls over from the old. Then I re-assign the superclass and remap the delegates.

I wish I had a better solution, but this has worked for me.

Also, if you were not using AutoLayout in the previous XCode project, keep an eye out for that in Xcode 5 its a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this logic in your code.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

And read this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html) carefully.